# Accessing computer management asks for admin password?

Tags: windows-7, windows

When i go to **start**->left click **computer** ->**manage**

it asks for password.Is it supposed to ask for password at this stage.

Also, is there any way to know when is the administrator on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer Management requires Administrator privileges, so yes, if the current user is not an administrator, it will ask for an administrator account and password.

You can go to Control Panel -> User Accounts to see the list of users on your machine.

Comment: i dont see User accounts in control panel

Comment: You must have missed it. If you view by Category, it's in the top right of the page. If you view by large/small icons, the icons are arranged alphabetically and it's near the end.